# mongodb - $dateFromString to support multiple format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a string field in mongodb which should be converted to a date field.
The format of the string is like the following:

```
  2014 - Only year, default month and day are 01 and 01, so it should be converted to date '2014-01-01'
  2014-01 - With year and month, which should also be converted to date '2014-01-01'
  2014-01-01 - Full date
```

`$dateFromString` in the following syntax doesn't seem to work:

```
$dateFromString: {
  dateString: '$order.date',
  format: '%Y-%m-%d',
}
```

How can I make `$dateFromString` to support multiple format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to add a new field via [`$addFields`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) and then for its value create few `if` conditions using the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) pipeline operator matching each of your date lengths (via [`$strLenCP`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#exp._S_strLenCP)) and concatenating the remaining parts (via [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)). Then since all of your date fields will now match the format `%Y-%m-%d` it should work ... like this:

```
db.getCollection('<YourCol>').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
      dateFixed: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [{ $strLenCP: "$date"}, 4] },       // <-- "2011"
          then: { $concat: ["$date", "-01-01"] },
          else: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [{ $strLenCP: "$date" }, 7] },  // <-- "2011-01"
              then: { $concat: ["$date", "-01"] },
              else: "$date"                              // <-- "2011-01-01"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: 'dateFixed',
          format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can [see it working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9i4-8XGhRgG)